# Is there a way to get API data with many API Keys to Power BI using Power Query?

Tags: json, api, powerbi, powerquery, api-key

***See solution below!***

I have to get data to PowerBI from one API with several API Keys. Each Key lets me get data from different branch of organization. Data structure is always the same. Since I have tens of API Keys I would like to do this with Power Query. After hours of Googling, my brain is overheating :).

What I have is API URL and list of API keys. There is no pagination. I can get data with one API Key without problems.

What i would like to do:

1. is to get a API key from list and put it into Json-call (Json.Document) as a variable
2. get Json and join it to previous if it exists
3. iterate this as long as there are API keys in list
4. make Json to a table

As a result there would be one table having data from all organization branches in it.

I have managed to find out that this could be done using List.Generate -function but I am stuck there.

```
let
    KeyList = {"abcd1234","bcde1234","defg1234"}, //list of API Keys 
    Source = "https://something.com/api/v1/" & "Items", // API URL
    Position = 0, // Starting position for API Key list

    GetJson =
        (Source, Position) as record =>
            let
                ApiData = Json.Document(Web.Contents(Source, [Headers=[#"X-API-Key"=KeyList{Position}]]))
            in
                ApiData,
    AllJson = 
        List.Generate (
            () => [i=0, Fetch = GetJson(Source,Position)],
            each [i]<=List.Count(KeyList),
            each [i=[i]+1, Fetch = GetJson([Source][i])],
            each [Fetch]
        ),
    Table = Table.FromList(AllJson, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    Table
```

This Power Query doesn't give any syntax errors, but there is something wrong in it's logic. It results a list of four errors, first of which saying there is trouble converting list to record and rest three are about not finding field Source.

Sorry I can't give real API Url and Keys.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

---

With Dreekun's help I managed to solve this. I'll put the corrected "code" below if someone is interested.

```
let
    KeyList = {"abcd1234","bcde1234","defg1234"}, //list of API Keys 
    Position = 0, // Starting position for API Key list

    GetJson =
        (Position) =>
            let
                ApiData = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://something.com/api/v1/" & "Items", [Headers=[#"X-API-Key"=KeyList{Position}]]))
            in
                ApiData,
    AllJson = 
        List.Generate (
            () => [i=1, Fetch = GetJson(Position)], // Note that counter i starts as 1, otherwise first key will be fetched twice
            each [i]<=List.Count(KeyList), // repeat until counter i is equal or greater than the length of key list
            each [i=[i]+1, Fetch = GetJson([i])] // add one to counter and fetch json data
        ),
    Table = Table.FromList(AllJson, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    Table
```

Thanks again Dreekun for help!! In this example there are three API Keys, but in real life I have more than fifty of them, so this helps a lot!

Comment: Json.Document returns a list of records, so you might want to take "as record" out of your function GetJson. See what you get. As for the rest I'm really not sure... KeyList works well with position? Maybe hard coding the keys in different variables would be enough?

Comment: Great, thanks!! Removing "as record" really worked. Now, I get first set of data. I have to work with KeyList as you suggested.

Comment: Good! You can even replace "as record" by "as list", since it is a list that is returned. The KeyList that I suggested might not be better than what you have implemented. You're using a method that people use to fetch paginated data, but with different keys instead of pages. IDK, it could work with a bit of trial and error.
EDIT: Ok you solved it! Nice work :)